# writing MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a `Table1` with structure as follows:

```
Database  name    value
SYSTEM    SCOTT    2
SYSTEM    SCOTT    4
SYSTEM    SCOTT    5
ORCL      TEST     4
ORCL      TEST     5
ORCL      TEST     7
```

Another `Table2` with structure as follows:-

```
Database1 name1 value1 database2 name2 value2
```

Now, I want a query which will insert the values from `Table1` to `Table2`, such that the `Table2` will appear as shown below:-

```
Database1    name1   value1   database2  name2   value2.
SYSTEM       SCOTT    2        ORCL       TEST    4
SYSTEM       SCOTT    4        ORCL       TEST    5
SYSTEM       SCOTT    5        ORCL       TEST    7
```

How can I achieve this table? I am guessing that some `GROUPBY` operations will give me the result, but I am not getting the exact query for this.

Comment: how do you know which values should be in database1 and database2?

Comment: @Arion In `table1` two types of databases are there, `SYSTEM` and `ORCL`, so the `database1` and `database2` will consist of the two types of databases i.e. `SYSTEM` and `ORCL`.

Comment: Arion is correct, you have no correlation that says the first "SYSTEM" record goes to the first "ORCL" record, same with second and third, nor WHY the relationship "SCOTT" vs "TEST".

Comment: I agree with Arion and DRapp. On a side note, `Table2` seems to me like a bad table design...hope you're not dropping the `Table1` structure in favor of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Insert & Union operation simply ..

Answer (score 0):

If the number of queries isn't important, that that can be done with two insert...select queries, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html.